# Codeigniter form validation many conditions in checking duplicate

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

Is there a way in codeigniter form validation library to determine a duplicate entry of a persons data if i considered a condition like this:
First Name, Middle Name, Last name, Birth Date is matched in db.

For example i need to check if this person is already exist if the data is matched from the DB considered the-same: First Name,Middle Name, Last name, and Birthdate.

I cannot use `is_unique` every input type in this situation because what if the person has the same First Name, Last Name and Middle name but the birthdate is different. How can i make a form validation like this in codeigniter?.

Something a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(patient_id) AS patient_id FROM patients WHERE patients.firstname = "" AND patients.middlename = "" AND patients.lastname = "" AND patients.birthdate = ""
```

if the query results greater than 1 , then it is considered a duplicate entry. how can i do that in codeigniter form validation?

Here is my code in Controller:

```
public function addpatient() {

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('pafname', 'pafname', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'First name is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('pamname', 'pamname', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Middle name is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('palname', 'palname', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Last name is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('paaddress', 'paaddress', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Address is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('pacontact', 'pacontact', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Contact # is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('pabdate', 'pabdate', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Birthdate is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('psex', 'psex', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Gender is required')
            );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('pmartialstat', 'pmartialstat', 'trim|required',
            array('required' => 'Martial status is required')
            );

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                    $result['status'] = true;
                    $result['message'] = "This patient has no duplicate";
            }else {
                $result['status'] = false;

                $result['message'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own [custom validation method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods). In the custom validation method call the SQL to see if there is a record where all the fields match and return back TRUE/FALSE based off the match.

Something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pafname', 'pafname', 'trim|required|callback__duplicate_validation',
        array('required' => 'First name is required',
              'callback__duplicate_validation' => 'Duplicate record')
        );

function _duplicate_validation($pafname) {
    // Get _POST data for all fields since only pafname is passed in
    // Call SQL to see if duplicate
    // if duplicate, return FALSE
    // else return TRUE
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sir, what you've answered is only for firstname, what if considered i need fname,middlename,lastname and birthday in my condition ? ..

Comment: Codeigniter form validation only passes in one parameter at a time. Since your validation needs all the fields, you would need to pull all fields from the $_POST data in the custom validation